# I have to get a pdf mainstream using itexsharp after have add a password

Tags: vb.net, pdf, passwords, itext

I am writing code for add a password in a pdf (I have an array of byte, not a file in a dir) but i have problem with outputStream (I need another array but protect from password): it is 15 bite and not contains the start pdf. I use a itexsharp 5.5 version, is not young but not very old, how is the error?

thi is my code:

```
   Dim PasswordUser As String = ""
        Dim UserPassByte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(PasswordUser)
        Dim ownerPassword As String = "1"
        Dim ownerPassByte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ownerPassword)
        Dim reader As New PdfReader("c:\tmp\pdfx.pdf")
        Dim array As Byte()
        Using outputStream As New MemoryStream
            Dim PdfStamper As New PdfStamper(reader, outputStream)
            PdfStamper.SetEncryption(UserPassByte, ownerPassByte, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128)
            PdfStamper.FormFlattening = True
            array = outputStream.ToArray()
        End Using
```

Comment: You forgot to close the `PdfStamper` before retrieving the bytes.

Comment: yes mkl, it need PdfStamper.Close.